# sparkviewengine alternative for WebForms project

Tags: asp.net, webforms, spark-view-engine, webforms-view-engine

I like the html dominated structure of the sparkviewengine very much.
Is there a version of it for WebForms projects?
I want to use it for generating presentation only  html (I mean, the output will not contain any html  input controls).
Or can you recommend an alternative?
VS.Net 2010 Framework 4.0

thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, traditional ASP.NET WebForms does not allow the developer to switch out View Engines. There is only one and that's WebForms. Only with ASP.NET MVC did this concept of interchangeable view engines come about which gave you the option.

If the View Engine in traditional ASP.NET was switchable, then you would have been able to use the Spark view engine because it already understands the `<%=blah %>` syntax and delegates that rendering, but I'm afraid the extensibility points are just not there...

**Update**
I stumbled across [this blog post](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Cristian-Libardo/Dates/2010/11/Spark-View-Engine-on-WebForms/) which talks about using Spark on the WebForms project - you may have some luck following up on that...

Hope that helps,
Rob